# Delphi SOAP request by HTTPRIO ContentType application/soap+xml

Tags: delphi, soap

I'm developing a SOAP client request for connecting to an https server.
Server require content type  application/soap+xml, bud HTTPRIO can send text/html.

I found const ContentType12UTF8 = 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8';

```
function THTTPReqResp.GetContentType: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if not (wnoSOAP12 in GetWebNodeOptions) then
  begin
    if UseUTF8InHeader then
      Result := ContentTypeUTF8
    else
      Result := ContentTypeNoUTF8;
  end
  else
  begin
    if UseUTF8InHeader then
      Result := Format(ContentTypeWithActionNoLabelFmt, [ContentType12UTF8, GetSOAPAction])
    else
      Result := Format(ContentTypeWithActionNoLabelFmt, [ContentType12NoUTF8, GetSOAPAction]);
  end;
end;
```

HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.WebNodeOption is set wnoSOAP12
also set UseUTF8InHeader := True

Delphi XE7

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: If I try anything there is still text/html ContentType.

Comment: I need change it to applicatio/soap+xml